# Should gender be revealed early for a healthy child?

Tags: humanoid, sex, medical, children

My Keplerians are externally gender neutral for 5 years. Now genetic testing will reveal gender but they don't do routine genetic testing.

Obviously if a young Keplerian goes to the doctor due to abdominal issues such as abdominal pain, an ultrasound or other form of medical imaging will be used to scan the abdomen and in the process the gender will be revealed(so for example if a CAT scan of the bladder is done to rule out stones, the uterus or prostate will show up thus revealing not only if there are stones in the bladder but also whether the Keplerian is male or female).

But for Keplerians who are healthy, should they get a gender reveal ultrasound at their next checkup or wait until they are 5 years old to see the results of a small spike in hormones? And what besides being rich would factor in to whether a gender reveal ultrasound is done or not?

Comment: When you say "My Keplerians", what are you referring to?

Comment: It would depend on their culture, wouldn't it? Whether it's the done thing or not. Or did you mean is it safer from a medical standpoint if they know more about their bodies?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as primarily opinion based as it seems to be asking us what a culture would do without giving us any information on the culture.

Comment: I would actually suggest taking this question, reframing it into a question about ethics, and asking on philosophy stack exchange. This is the kind of question I'm sure many philosophers have written a lot of interesting things about

Comment: Who cares? Why would the child's sex at that stage be significant to anyone?

Comment: Gender is a social construct. There is no way a genetic test can reveal gender. What a genetic test reveals is *sex*. Maybe Keplerians are stuffy and old fashioned and equate biological sex with social gender, and then maybe not. If they do have an inclination to equate social gender with biological sex, the way humans do, then it may be useful or expected to begin indoctrination in the socially accepted behaviors at a tender age. For example, male and female human children are not really physically different until puberty, yet we routinely instill masculine and feminine behaviors early.

Comment: Depends on the amount of sexual dimorphism in adult Keplerians. There could be an advantage to getting an early start on sex specific skills (military training, some type of sport, etc). There is also a 5 year delay before you find out if you got your first boy, perhaps to pass on inherited titles or something, so knowing early can tell you to have another kid.

Comment: I think you're using the word "gender" incorrectly in this scenario.  _Gender_ is the sum of societal roles, responsibilities and expectations in a culture.  It is the male gender in China that cares for his aging parents. This, incidentally, was why the one-child policy backfired and prompted sex-based abortion spikes in China.  Male children stay at home to care for their elderly parents, albeit indirectly, as it is his wife who moves in and provides elder care. In a family with only a daughter, she was "worthless", when she married she would leave her family without no one to care for them.

Answer (score 2):

Health reasons.

This may trigger some.... However there are biological differences between males and females as a rule. 
So in order for the child to mature there might be a health risk in that process or after it occurs. 
Because it will most likely be an accelerated process.

In the end I see no reason not to reveal it if it is possible!